# Regular expression for complicated username

Tags: regex

I want an regex for username that should contain

1. at least 6 characters
2. It may include uppercase and lowercase letters
3. It also must include either:at least one number; or one of these symbols:_@/-
4. It should not allow space in start and in between.

My regex is

```
   /^((?=.*[a-zA-Z]))((?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[_@/-])).{6,20}$/
```

what is wrong in this. It allows space but i dont want to allow space.
please suggest answer.

Comment: What part of your regex do you think would forbid spaces?

Comment: Why is there a letter required in the second position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work

```
^(?=.*?[0-9_@/-])(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9_@/-]{6,20}$
```